# Find the solutions to $4x \equiv 16 \pmod{20}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the solutions to $4x \equiv 16 \pmod{20}$

I managed to determine this by writing $4x = 16 + 20j \implies x =4 +5j \implies x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, but the official solution stated that the solutions are $x = 4,9,14,19 \pmod{20}$ which I'm not entirely sure how they got?

Comment: As in the proof in the linked dupe,  using $\rm\color{#c00}{mDL}$ = [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) we have

$$\large \begin{align}\bmod 20\!:\ x &\equiv 4+5j \\
&\equiv 4 + (5j\bmod  20)\\
&\equiv 4 + 5(\color{#0a0}{j\bmod  4})\ \ {\rm by}\,\ \rm\color{#c00}{mDL}\\
&\equiv 4 + 5\color{#0a0}{\{0,1,2,3\}}\\
&\equiv 4,\,9,\,14,\,19
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: Your solution and the official solution are the same!