# If $x\equiv a\pmod{n}$, prove that either $x\equiv a\pmod{2n}$ or $x\equiv a+n\pmod{2n}.$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> If $x\equiv  a\pmod{n}$, prove that either $x\equiv a\pmod{2n}$ or $x\equiv a+n\pmod{2n}.$

Well I am a bit stuck in this congruence problem. I tried out :-

$n\vert x-a$ so for $2n|x-a$, $x-a$ must be even but I am not able to prove what if $x-a$ is odd, how can I prove that $x-(a+n)$ will be even and divisible by $2n$. Is this the right approach? Though it seems a very vague one, I can't think of any other.

Comment: As in the proof in the linked dupe, using $ \rm\color{#c00}{mDL}=$ [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) we have

$$\large \begin{align}\bmod 2n\!:\ x &\equiv a+kn,\, \ {\rm by}\,\ x\equiv a\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!n} \\ 
&\equiv a + (kn\bmod  2n)\\ 
&\equiv a + n(\color{#0a0}{k\bmod  2})\ \ {\rm by}\,\ \rm\color{#c00}{mDL}\\ &\equiv a + n\color{#0a0}{\{0,1\}}\\ &\equiv a,\: a+n \end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4036574/242) for another example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The hypothesis means that $x = a + kn$ for some integer $k$. What can you conclude about $x$ modulo $2n$ when $k$ is even? How about when $k$ is odd?